# To convert a data obtained through URL to post variables

Tags: php, html, post

I need to read the result of a form which uses POST action type for submission. So, can I convert a variable obtained through GET variable to POST and then I can simply read the contents using file_get_contents().

Please help me in getting the data using this method or through some alternate method if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can be used to perform POST requests by using [stream_context_create](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php):

```
$options = array('http'=>array(
        'method'=>'POST',
        'header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content'=>'var1=a&var2=b'
    )
);

echo file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/someform/', false, stream_context_create($options));
```

Comment: But I have a problem with this. I am unable to set a variable value a, b to the parameters passed. I am using this code to extract the regno (my parameter) from url using this code:-

Comment: `var p = document.location.href;
var p_1 = p.split("=");
var req = p_1[1];`

Answer (score 1):

All parameters passed into your PHP from a form will be populated in the superglobal [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

If you're uncertain as to whether the parameter will be given via GET or POST, you can use the superglobal [`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: + $_REQUEST contains the contents of $_COOKIE

Comment: `var p = document.location.href;
var p_1 = p.split("=");
var req = p_1[1];`