# Post variables to another PHP file

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To convert a data obtained through URL to post variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192822/to-convert-a-data-obtained-through-url-to-post-variables)

I receive some values in $_GET array, I would like to **redirect** a user to another PHP file, but I need to send all values in my GET array to that file as a POST request, is this posible? how?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this using curl.

https://www.php.net/curl

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` is what you're gonna need.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the Curl library. you can find a sample [HERE](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl).

Comment: Note that this doesn't redirect the browser or anything, it will only make the post request.

Comment: is there a way to also redirect the user?

Comment: It depend of what you mean by "redirect". The curl execution could return HTML content, which could be displayed to the user. It is not a "redirect", but user will see the POST query result.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a post request in behalve of the browser. So you can't redirect a user to the other file, and expecting it to be a POST request.

As Arcadien said, you could use Curl to make a POST request, but the user won't notice anything, because the request is sent from your server to your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do an actual redirect (where the user's browser is actually *loads* the destination URL), then I think the cleanest way is with javascript; the basic idea would be to write a self-submitting form. Pre-populate the form with all the get variables as input type="hidden", and then write a little unload handler to submit it.

If you don't care about the user-agent loading a new URL, and the other file is on your server but it just expects those variables in POST instead of GET, you can just copy the values over and include the file `$_POST = $_GET;`

Comment: That's a workaround, the problem is that I wouldn't like to show those values to the user in the URL.

Comment: If you already have them in GET, they are there. Then if you use an auto-submitting form which is POST, they will *not* be in the URL in the second page load (which will happen almost immediately)